# postgresql : updating all rows in one column via trigger in large table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am wanting to run a trigger to re-populate a column across all rows on a large table 6m+. What I am doing atm, is dropping all indexes, then just running a `update "col" set id=id` across all rows. Is this the most efficient method for something like this, or should i be doing it in blocks of 1k 10k ?

database: postgresql 9.5

Comment: It will be less efficient to do it in multiple statements. Dropping indexes and doing it in a single hit is probably the most efficient way.

Comment: not having the column at all may be more efficient.

Comment: lol, if only life was that simple ;)